# How to set active Tab in (angular Material Design) in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I know I am not the new to ask this but I could not find any solution for this .

I have a material tab control in one of the component .But It's not showing the active tab until I click on anyone of the tab in the page .

app.component.html

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar  mat-align-tabs="center" mat-stretch-tabs >
  <a  mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of NavigateTo" [routerLink]="link.path" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
 NavigateTo : Array<object> = [
                         {label:'Employee Master',path:'EmployeeMaster',index:0},
                         {label:'Table Master',path:'TableMaster',index:1}
                        ];
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want a specific tab to be active when you navigate to the component?

Comment: @wentjun yes,exactly

Comment: And that specific tab depends on the route, right? For example, `www.example.com/EmployeeMaster` will have the tab with `EmployeeMaster` set as active?

Comment: @wentjun yes ,you're right

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard for me to actively debug it for you unless you can reproduce the issue on stackblitz, but here is my hypothesis:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar  mat-align-tabs="center" mat-stretch-tabs >
  <a  mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of NavigateTo" [routerLink]="link.path" (click)="activeLinkIndex = link.index" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="activeLinkIndex===link.index">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the following changes on the component. I have only added the pseudo code, but the idea is that you map your route parameters to the specific index in `NavigateTo`. In addition, you might need to add `/` to your link paths:

```
activeLinkIndex = 0;

.
.
//this.activeLinkIndex = 
// map the current route parameter to this.NavigateTo and get the desired route index
 .
 .
NavigateTo : Array<object> = [
  {label:'Employee Master',path:'/EmployeeMaster',index:0},
  {label:'Table Master',path:'/TableMaster',index:1}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're probably not on one of the routes as specified in the second code snippet.

You can either:

- Redirect all routes to one of the paths that you specified:

  ```ts
  import { Route } from '@angular/router';
  // ...
  export const AppRoutes: Route[] = [
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/<your-path>' }
  ]
  ```
- Or set the initial route to redirect to:

  ```ts
  import { Route } from '@angular/router';
  // ...
  export const AppRoutes: Route[] = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/<your-path>' }
  ]
  ```